# Matplotlib figure annotations outside of window

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I am making a program that implements a matplotlib pie/donut chart into a tkinter window to illustrate some data, however, I have added "annotations" or labels from each wedge of the pie chart. Because of this the window that opens when I execute the code fits the chart itself, but the labels are cut off at the edges of the window. Specifically, it looks like this...
[image]

Note the top two arrows don't actually have text attached to the corresponding labels so the situation is actually worse than my screenshot depicts.

Even if I get rid of the code related to generating a tkinter GUI, and just try to execute code to generate a regular figure window the labels are initially cut-off. But, if I use the built in zoom-out functionality I can zoom out the make the labels fit.

I have tried to adjust the figsize here...

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4), subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))
```

yet it makes no difference. Hopefully there is a solution, thanks...

Here is my full code if anyone needs...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

player1_cards = {'Mustard', 'Plum', 'Revolver', 'Rope', 'Ballroom', 'Library'}
player2_cards = {'Scarlet', 'White', 'Candlestick'}
player3_cards = {'Green', 'Library', 'Kitchen', 'Conservatory'}
middle_cards = {'Peacock'}
unknown_cards = {'Lead Pipe', 'Wrench', 'Knife', 'Hall', 'Lounge', 'Dining Room', 'Study'}

player1_string = ', '.join(player1_cards)
player1_string = player1_string.replace(', ', '\n')

player2_string = ', '.join(player2_cards)
player2_string = player2_string.replace(', ', '\n')

player3_string = ', '.join(player3_cards)
player3_string = player3_string.replace(', ', '\n')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4), subplot_kw=dict(aspect="equal"))

recipe = [player1_string, player2_string, player3_string, '', '']
data = [len(player1_cards), len(player2_cards), len(player3_cards), 1, 7]
cols = ['#339E5A', '#26823E', '#0C5D2E', '#98D6AE', '#5EC488']

wedges, texts = ax.pie(data, wedgeprops=dict(width=0.5), startangle=90, colors = cols)

for w in wedges:
    w.set_linewidth(4)
    w.set_edgecolor('white')

bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="square,pad=0.3", fc="w", ec="white", lw=0.72)
kw = dict(xycoords='data', textcoords='data',  arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-"), bbox=bbox_props, zorder=0, va="center")

for i, p in enumerate(wedges):
    ang = (p.theta2 - p.theta1)/2. + p.theta1
    y = np.sin(np.deg2rad(ang))
    x = np.cos(np.deg2rad(ang))
    horizontalalignment = {-1: "right", 1: "left"}[int(np.sign(x))]
    connectionstyle = "angle,angleA=0,angleB={}".format(ang)
    kw["arrowprops"].update({"connectionstyle": connectionstyle})
    ax.annotate(recipe[i], xy=(x, y), xytext=(x + np.sign(x)*.5, y*1.5),
             horizontalalignment=horizontalalignment, **kw, family = "Quicksand")

ax.set_title("Matplotlib bakery: A donut")

plt.show()
```

Comment: Is there a reason, why you loop two times over `wedges`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to play around with the subplot parameters to make space for the text outside the axes.

```
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=..., top=..., left=..., right=...)
```

E.g. in this case

```
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2, top=0.9)
```

seems to give a nice representation

[image]

Comment: Hi. Your screenshot depicts exactly what I was looking for. However, I am a tad bit confused where to implement this line of code in my program. I am really new with matplotlib. Thank you very much for helping me solve my problem.

Comment: You can place it anywhere between the point where you define the figure and the point where you `show` it.